# How to download a pdf file when you click on the button in html

Tags: html, pdf

I have an src folder in which there is a Files folder where the file "Garri_Potter_i_Taynaya_Komnata.pdf" is located and also in src there is a Pages folder in which there is a file with the code that I attached. Now, when you click on the button, the file is downloaded with the correct name, but it is empty, although the file in the Files folder is working.

```
<template>
    <div>

        <navbar></navbar>
        <div style="margin: 0 360px;">
            <h1>Моя библиотека</h1>
            <div class="container12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="myLibraryItem" v-for="book in myLibrary">
                    <div style="display: flex; align-items:flex-start;">
                        <img :src="book.image" class="item-image" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        <div class="item-details" style="font-size: 16px;">
                            <div class="author" style="font-weight: 600; margin-bottom: 5px;">{{ book.name }}</div>
                            <div class="name" style="color: rgb(63, 63, 63);">{{ book.author }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 115px;">
                        <a href="src/Files/src/Files/Garri_Potter_i_Taynaya_Komnata.pdf" download><button class="readBtn">Скачать</button></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>   
</template>
```

It doesn't even work for me to open a file in the browser without the download attribute when I click on the button

Comment: I noticed that I inserted "src/Files" twice, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: actually, your link should be only `/Files/Garri_Potter_i_Taynaya_Komnata.pdf` since it is relative to the place where the html is

Comment: @LelioFaieta no differents

Comment: @KJ I didn't write it very correctly, when I downloaded this file and I open it through WPS Office, then WPS Office gives me the error "this file type is not supported, or the file is corrupted"

Comment: that's a completely different error. Did you upload it to the server using FTP? Which method?